# ceph-deploy: error: unrecognized arguments: --data

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, openshift, ceph, apiconnect

I am trying to install ceph and configure on a mounted disk. I have the disk location, however, I face a problem when I use the --data parameter.

**command:** 
ceph-deploy osd create --data /home/ceph-admin/ceph-data/vda node-ip-address

**error:** 
ceph-deploy: error: unrecognized arguments: --data

**ceph version:**
ceph version 14.2.8 (2d095e947a02261ce61424021bb43bd3022d35cb) nautilus (stable)

**ceph-deploy version:** 
1.5.38

All the documentations I found uses the --data parameter. is there any workaround?

please help!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade your **ceph-deploy** to version **2.x** to be able to deploy nautilus to your cluster. The sample commands to update ceph-deploy on ubuntu.

```
$ wget -q -O- 'https://download.ceph.com/keys/release.asc' | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo deb https://download.ceph.com/debian-nautilus/ $(lsb_release -sc) main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ceph.list
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ceph-deploy
```

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing https://docs.ceph.com/docs/nautilus/man/8/ceph-deploy/#osd, I *believe* you need to point directly at a disk, not a filesystem path.

The example in https://docs.ceph.com/docs/nautilus/rados/deployment/ceph-deploy-osd/ also suggests so:

```
ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/ssd osd-server1
```

i.e. unmount `/home/ceph-admin/ceph-data/vda` and point directly to device location shown by `lsblk`.